# Welcome email going in spam Gmail

Tags: smtp, email, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES for my outbound emails and they directly land in the Gmail's spam where as in Yahoo and Hotmail/Outlook they land in the inbox.

I did some basic checking of the welcome email and here are some details:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of 000001458d959210-3a5c1a23-9bef-439d-8cdd-3f2f772d1cb2-000000@amazonses.com designates 54.240.9.91 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=000001458d959210-3a5c1a23-9bef-439d-8cdd-3f2f772d1cb2-000000@amazonses.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@optynmail.com
```

Port 25 Auth Results:

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

I also, use the same domain to send 3rd party marketing campaigns as well. The Feedback loop is also setup via Amazon SES and we take special care of unsubscribes, bounces and complaints to no repeatedly send emails.

Any help around this greatly appreciated.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

> I also, use the same domain to send 3rd party marketing campaigns

that sounds like the culprit. 
in general, if possible, try to separate your marketing and transactional email domains.

Comment: I am working on that actually using separate IP's for marketing and transactional emails. Hopefully that will fix the problem. Thanks for responding.